# How to create a numpy array of repeating values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

- Given the following array, where the elements in the array are a value at index `[0]`, and its frequency at index `[1]`.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[767, 5], [770, 5], [772, 7], [779, 7], [781, 5], [782, 7], [787, 5]])

# values
v = a[:, 0]

array([767, 770, 772, 779, 781, 782, 787])

# frequencies
f = a[:, 1]

array([5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 5])
```

- I need an array that is the length of the sum of the `frequencies`, filled with `v`, based on their respective frequency.

```py
[767, 767, 767, 767, 767, 770, 770, 770, 770, 770, 772, 772, 772, 772, 772, 772, 772, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 781, 781, 781, 781, 781, 782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 787, 787, 787, 787, 787]
```

- This can be done with

```py
# a for-loop
ix = list()

for (x, y) in a:
    l = [x] * y
    ix.extend(l)

# a list-comprehension
ix = [v for (x, y) in a for v in [x]*y]
```

- How can I do this with a vectorized `numpy` method?

  - No `for-loops`
  - No `pandas`
- I thought of creating an array of zeros, whose length is the sum of frequencies, but I'm not certain how to fill it.

```py
za = np.zeros(sum(f))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy.repeat`:

```
np.repeat(a[:, 0], a[:, 1])
# np.repeat(*a.T) # In case its (n, 2) shaped
```

Output:

```
array([767, 767, 767, 767, 767, 770, 770, 770, 770, 770, 772, 772, 772,
       772, 772, 772, 772, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 781, 781,
       781, 781, 781, 782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 782, 787, 787, 787,
       787, 787])
```